# Query in vb.net - good practice

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know which way querying is a better, safer, more efficient. And whether there are some major differences. Sending two examples of code. Would I need something to add, modify or delete. Feel free to express your opinion.

The first way:

```
     Try
        con.Close()
        con.Open()

        Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO tblPerson(ID, Name,Email,GenderID) VALUES(@ID, @Name,@Email,@GenderID)"
        com = New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con)

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", CInt(txtID.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", CStr(txtName.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", CStr(txtEmail.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GenderID", CInt(txtGender.Text))

        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        com.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        con.Close()
    Finally
        con.Close()

    End Try
```

and second:

```
    con.Close()
    con.Open()

    exe = "basicInsert"
    Dim startTransaction = con.BeginTransaction

    Try
        com = New SqlCommand("EXECUTE " & exe & " '" & txtID.EditValue & "','" & txtName.EditValue & "','" & txtEmail.EditValue & "','" & txtGender.EditValue & "'", con)

        com.Transaction = startTransaction

        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        com.dispose()

        startTransaction.Commit()

    Catch ex As Exception
        startTransaction.Rollback()
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType.ToString)

    End Try
```

Comment: First one, could use some work though...

Comment: You could import system.management class and use the classes to make this better and as s well as creating a stored procedure...

Comment: please show me the example!

Comment: The first one is safer that the second one, because the latter is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: At first example: `con.Close()` in catch is not needed. And start use Usings.

Comment: Ok, for con.close. why should I use the - 'using'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much always use the first option.  The second option can easily lead to syntax errors and leaves you open to SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you. Is there third way, may be safer and more effective than this two

Comment: The first way is basically the way you do it.  The details will vary from case to case but the principle is the same.